# ADF Iterator without table row selection

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

1.3
I have two adf tables, one for master and the second for details with master details transient VOs.
I am populating the rows to View Object programmatically, when delete any row the iterator contains only the details of selected row.
for Example:
1
-a
-b

2
-c
-d

3
-e
-f

when I deleted 2 the iterator contains only the sleected item: 1-a-b

```
         ViewObject masterVO = this.getSearchAttributesTrVO();
    masterVO.executeQuery();

    RowSet masterList = (RowSet) masterVO;
    Row[] master = masterList.getAllRowsInRange();

    for (int x = 0; x < master.length; x++) {
        Row masterRow = master[x];

        System.out.println("*** master AttributeId=" + master[x].getAttribute("AttributeId"));

        RowSet detailList = (RowSet) masterRow.getAttribute("ConditionsVO");
        Row[] detail = detailList.getAllRowsInRange();

        for (int y = 0; y < detail.length; y++) {
            System.out.println("*** detail Id/AttributeId=" + detail[y].getAttribute("Id") + "/" +
                               detail[y].getAttribute("AttributeId"));
        }
```

So I need to read all values in the VO not just the details of selected item.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using

```
while (master.hasNext()) {
//code here
   }
```